# Retain Messages until a Subscription is Made using Python + Stomp

Tags: python, python-2.7, message-queue, stomp

I am currently writing two scripts to subscribe to a message server using the *stomp* client library, *write.py* to write data and *read.py* to get data.

If I start *read.py* first and then run *write.py*, *write.py* receives the messages correctly.

However, if I run *write.py* first and then run *read.py*, *read.py* does not retrieve any messages previously sent to the server.

Below are relevant parts of the scripts.

How can I achieve that messages put into the queue by *write.py* are being retained until *read.py* subscribes and retrieves them?

**write.py**

```
def writeMQ(msg):
    queue = '/topic/test'
    conn = stomp.Connection(host_and_ports=[(MQ_SERVER, MQ_PORT)])
    try:
        conn.start()
        conn.connect(MQ_USER, MQ_PASSWD, wait=True)
        conn.send(body=msg, destination=queue, persistent=True)
    except:
        traceback.print_exc()
    finally:
        conn.disconnect()

    return
```

**read.py**

```
class MyListener(stomp.ConnectionListener):    
    def on_error(self, headers, message):    
        print ('received an error {0}'.format(message))    

    def on_message(self, headers, message):    
        print ('received an message {0}'.format(message))    


def readMQ():                                                
    queue = '/topic/test'     
    conn = stomp.Connection(host_and_ports=[(MQ_SERVER, MQ_PORT)])    
    try:                                                              
        conn.set_listener("", MyListener())                           
        conn.start()                                                  
        conn.connect(MQ_USER, MQ_PASSWD, wait=True)    

        conn.subscribe(destination=queue, ack="auto", id=1)                       


        stop = raw_input()                  
    except:                   
        traceback.print_exc()    
    finally:                     
        conn.disconnect()        

    return
```

Comment: Which messaging server are you using? You are talking about queues all the time, but from the looks of it you are sending the message to a topic and not a queue. Is that on purpose? How many clients are supposed to receive a single message?

Comment: @bbastu Only one client is supposed to receive a single message. The server is set up by another guy and I will check about the details. If I want to use queue rather than topic, do I need to do some modification on server or just update my code?

Comment: I assume that depends on the server. But with apollo (which I assume you are using) just set queue=/queue/test.

Comment: @bbastu Yes, set queue=/queue/test works, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the messages are being sent to a topic.

The [Apollo Documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/apollo/documentation/stomp-manual.html#Destination_Types) describes the difference between topics and queues as follows:

> Queues hold on to unconsumed messages even when there are no subscriptions attached, while a topic will drop messages when there are no connected subscriptions.

Thus, when *read.py* is startet first and listening, the topic recognizes the subscription and forwards the message. But when *write.py* is startet first the message is dropped because there is no subscribed client.

So you can use a queue instead of a topic. If the server is able to create a queue silently simply set

```
queue = '/queue/test' .
```

I don't know which version of stomp is being used, but I cannot find the parameter

```
send(..., persistent=True) .
```

Anyway persisting is not the right way to go since it still does not allow for messages to simply be retained for a later connection, but saves the messages in case of a server failure.

You can use the

```
retain:set
```

header for topic messages instead.

Comment: It seems that "persistent=True" is the usage in stompy.stomp, I just mix it up. I try to replace "persistent" with "per" and it still works, so I think parameter "persistent" is not used, and it is free to add extra parameters in function send.